# Best way to replace part of array with another array

Tags: python, list, replace

I'm looking for the most pythonic way of doing something like that:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
b = ['a','b','c']
c = replace(a,b,2)

c is now [1,2,'a','b','c',6,7,8]
```

Comment: you need to replace the part of array from index 2? that is the third parameter?

Comment: What's your guess? have you searched for proper functions or methods that might be useful for this task?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can slice your list accordingly!

- That is, with `a` and `b` being your initial list and the one that you want to replace from index `s`, `a[:s]` will get all elements before from 0 to s that is (`[1,2]`).
- `a[s+len(b):]`  will get all items from index `s` to `len(b)`, that is (`[6,7,8]`)

so when you concatenate the first result along with b and then the second result you can get the desired output!

`a[:s]+b+a[s+len(b):]`

So,

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> b = ['a','b','c']
>>> replace=lambda a,b,s:a[:s]+b+a[s+len(b):]
>>> c = replace(a,b,2)
>>> print c
[1, 2, 'a', 'b', 'c', 6, 7, 8]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: pythonic answer :)

Answer (score 8):

Okay, here is another simple way to do this:
(Edit: forgot slicing a to copy it into c)

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
b = ['a','b','c']
c=a[:]
c[2:5]=b
print(c)
```

Or, when you want to replace in place:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
b = ['a','b','c']
a[2:5]=b
print(a)
```

Hope I helped!

Comment: this replace the original list!! that is even `a` is affected!

Comment: @Keiwan +1 for using  `a=a[:]`

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed and edited. Thank you @Keiwan

Comment: That is a very tricky python feature in my opinion!

Comment: This is really cool, and is simpler than the accepted answer. Thanks!